# Activation="sigmoid" still giving me an accuracy of 0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I keep getting a 0 accuracy with `tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name="binary_accuracy", dtype=None, threshold=0.5)`
New to ML, so not exactly sure what I am doing wrong here. This is my model:

```py
def search_model_gru_cnn(hp):
    # Hyperparameters
    lr = hp.Float("lr", min_value=1e-4, max_value=1e-2, sampling="LOG")
    dense_dropout = hp.Float("dense_dropout", min_value=0.0, max_value=0.5, step=0.05)
    use_batch_norm = hp.Boolean("use_batch_norm", default=False)

    conv_filters = hp.Int("conv_filters", min_value=32, max_value=128, step=16)
    conv_kernel_size = hp.Int("conv_kernel_size", min_value=3, max_value=7, step=2)

    gru_units = hp.Int("gru_units", min_value=32, max_value=256, step=8)

    dense_units = hp.Int("dense_units", min_value=16, max_value=128, step=4)

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    model.add(
        tf.keras.layers.GRU(
            gru_units,
            return_sequences=True,
        )
    )

    model.add(
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
            filters=conv_filters,
            kernel_size=conv_kernel_size,
            activation="relu",
            input_shape=(X_train_scaled.shape[1], X_train_scaled.shape[2]),
        )
    )
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

    if use_batch_norm:
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(dense_units))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dense_dropout))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            units=1,
            activation="sigmoid",
        )
    )

    # Compile the model
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
        metrics=[
            tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(
                name="binary_accuracy", dtype=None, threshold=0.5
            )
        ],
    )

    return model
```

EDIT: Added a `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())` before the output layer as there is a y_true and y_pred shape mismatch. Even after using a flattening layer I still have:
`Shape of y_true: [72 1]`
`Shape of y_pred: [72 14 1]`

As you can see the activation function of the last dense layer is sigmoid, which should be correct for my dataset. Target values are `int` 0's and 1's.

Results:

```
Epoch 4/120
439/439 [==============================] - 7s 17ms/step - loss: -0.1974 - binary_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.8577 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

The dataset has no missing/inf values.

Comment: You have negative loss, are you sure all of your targets are positive?

Comment: You probably do not have binary labels, which is expected in your setup, what exactly are your labels?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I checked that. They're all 0's and 1's. --> `target_series = (target_series > 0).astype(int)`

Comment: @Frightera just checked and yes, they're all either 0 or 1

Comment: @Frightera just read that a negative loss is not what it is supposed to be... trying to figure out what is going wrong here..

Comment: Again, they are probably not 0/1, because a label bigger than one would produce negative BCE loss.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy sorry, I just saw my mistake and feel so embarrassed. I....was scaling the target values.